# Chrome always re requesting images in Raphael image element

Tags: image, google-chrome, request, raphael, flicker

I use a hover function like this which works fine when using external image sources
http://jsfiddle.net/Fftfv/5/

```
var paper = new Raphael("game-frame",600,600);
obj =  paper.image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/French_suits.svg/300px-French_suits.svg.png", 100, 100, 300, 300).hover(function () {

this.toFront();
this.animate({ transform: 's1.6'}, 50, 'linear');
},function() {

this.animate({ transform: 's1'}, 50, 'linear');
});
```

The problem is i take my images from my site so my img source looks like "images/a5.png" in this case chrome requests the image every time something is done to it like hover.
In firefox this works fine as it uses the already loaded image.

Comment: try with full path to image on your server

Comment: Have you disabled cache in chrome, check your settings in the dev tools.

Comment: Friend with who i am making this project already tested it and i just did it myself. The images get saved into the local cache but still get requested again.

Answer (score 0):

OK i found the problem i was running my node.js server in development mode, changed it to production and it worked